# How to set Tabbar position at center in android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-tablayout

I have to design a screen where at the top I need to show some user details and then at center I have a tab bar and bottom part will show the page selected from the tab. But I am not able to show the tabbar at center. It can set either at top or bottom of the screen. How can I set the tabbars at center so that we can show some information at top of the bar and show the selected page of tabs at bottom part?

In this example image I need to show the user profile pic, username, and some other details of user at top where "Material is good" written. and below that the tabbar like this image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create View pager, Tab Layout, fragments etc..
below is the project that i made similar to your request go though it...

[Hers the github link](https://github.com/AshwithJoylan/Tab)

i hope it helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve it like following screenshot?
[image]

If so , you could download [this demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/UserInterface/TreePager/), Then changed Main.axml like following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="name tom"
        />
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="age 10"
        />
</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
android:id="@+id/viewpager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="50">

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="top"

  android:paddingTop="10dp"
  android:textColor="#fff" />

 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

 </LinearLayout>
```